# How to increase dedicated video ram windows 8?

Tags: memory

I have Asus x75a and I would like to know if there is any way to increase dedicated ram because it's only poor 32mb.

**Graphics info:**
[image]

**System info:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check your BIOS for a setting that might allow you to set the dedicated video RAM to a different value. If that is not available, then unfortunately you will not be able to change the *dedicated* amount of RAM reserved for the Intel Graphics.

Luckily, the shared pool of memory, **1632 MB**, is available for both your CPU and the GPU. This means that the GPU will use more system RAM if necessary up to **1664 MB**.